# WordPress.org adding low level code/Adding in external APIs?

Tags: wordpress

I am very confused with how Wordpress works and how I am supposed to code in it.

I have an API that lets me generate an online whiteboard people can use to draw things and I want it to generate after a user is logged in and clicks a button. However, I don't get how to edit the low level code of WordPress at all and it is driving me crazy.

Is there a difference between using WordPress and the WordPress.org website interface? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference.  No, you don't edit the core (unless you want to break the auto-updating functionality and expose your site to hackers), and lastly it is actually pretty easy - https://developer.wordpress.org/

Comment: You are going to interact with WP using action and filter hooks. Actions will let you place your code at specific parts of WP. Filters will let you modify values of stuff at different parts of WP. The best way to start is writing a plugin: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: ps: I'm not writing a proper answer because I think the question is off-topic for the site, it's too broad and doesn't have a programming issue to be solved. It's a nice discussion for a webchat, or a forum like Reddit. SO is not the right format for it...